# If a square matrix is not orthogonally diagonisable can it be orthogonally similar to an upper triangular matrix T

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that every square matrix is similar to an upper triangular matrix, but does this imply orthogonal similarity?

Answer (score 1):

Every square matrix is similar to an upper triangular matrix **if** you allow for matrices with complex entries.  Additionally, every matrix with complex entries is **unitarily** similar to an upper triangular matrix, as described by a matrix's [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition).  We can further state that every matrix with real entries is **orthogonally** similar to a block upper-triangular matrix, as described by a matrix's [real Schur decomposition](http://kurser.lobner.dk/LinAlg/Tilf%C2%B0jelser%20til%20Leons%20bog/RealSchur.pdf).

Comment: "every matrix with real entries is orthogonally similar to a block upper-triangular matrix" - sometimes called the "Murnaghan-Winter theorem"

Comment: @J.M. Never heard that name, cool